# is there a way to pass a variable in the byte string b''?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to pass a variable in the b'' but it always converts the name of the variable in byte.

```
    string = 'this is a string'
    print(string)
    string = b'string'
    print(string)

Result:

    this is a string
    b'string'
```

but the result which i want is 
b'this is a string'

Comment: If you want `string` as a byte-string, why not `bytes(string, 'utf8')`?

Comment: if i have a string of text in utf-32 encoding how can I convert it into string of utf-8 encoding

Comment: \xff\xfe\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00r\x00\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00g\x00\x00\x00                                       i want to convert this text to utf-8 encoding

Comment: Could you [edit] to clarify what you're trying to achieve? This currently seems like an XY problem.

Comment: just to clarify XY problem : `Asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b'string'` is the literal word "string" as bytes, not a variable substitution. You need to encode your variable as bytes separately.

```py
string = 'this is a string'
print(string)
as_bytes = bytes(string, 'utf8')
print(as_bytes)
b'this is a string'
```